# Weird "shadow lines" on my display

Tags: graphics-card, display

These things exist only from time to time, restarting and resetting the display doesn't help. These lines are shown Any idea what could be the cause or the solution? I feel like it's something really simple but couldn't find it on the web.

I have NVIDIA GeForce GTX 750 Ti

[image]

Comment: I can see nothing wrong with your screenshot. If it's a screen defect (not faulty GPU) it won't appear on screenshots, you'd have to take a photo.

Comment: I seriously considered getting my eyes checked until @gronostaj commented

Comment: Dammit.. I'll upload the photo right now.

Comment: Nothing in the screenshot looks wrong to me. Perhaps upload a better screenshot or picture?

Comment: I've added the photo of the display

Comment: ...aaand everyone has left.

Comment: What kind of cable are you using to connect monitor to graphics card?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It was a cable connection issue. After adjusting it, the lines disappear. It's not HDMI, maybe I need to get HDMI...